# How to pass all integers from ArrayList into static int variable, deviding them with "|" sign?

Tags: java, android, arrays

For instance, I have:

```
ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3));
```

And I need to get eventually this:

```
public static final int CATEGORY = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3;
```

How can I pass these numbers to int like that?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: You can't. In an `int` field, you can only store a single integer. The `|` you are using is a bitwise OR in Java. This means that `0 | 1 | 2 | 3` results in the bitwise OR of `00, 01, 10 and 11`, being `11`. If you want to store multiple integers, then the most common options to store them are inside an array (`int[]`) or a `List`.